# Seeing Out of memory when working with mongodb changeStreams

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-streams

I am using changeStreams https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/ to look at changes and port it to a different system.

The code looks like below

```
const collection = db.collection('inventory');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // process next document
});
```

At some point, we update names at mongo level directly which produces big chunk of data for above code. It causes system to go out of memory.

Does using iterator method solve the above issue and not receive full chunk of data?

```
const collection = db.collection('inventory');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
const next = await changeStream.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.4/classes/ChangeStream.html#next says:

> Get the **next** available document from the Change Stream.

You should read it as "get 1 document" not "full chunk of data".

The event is emitted on each matching change in the oplog. It's a process, means there is no clear boundary when one "full chunk of data" would stop and the next "full chunk of data" would start.

Using `await ....next()` syntax, you need to put in in the loop to call the iterator for each new change.

No changes in javascript code would solve the memory issue without changing your architecture though.

The problem you are facing is the volume of changes is higher than your script can process. To address this issue you need make the listener as lightweight as possible, e.g. outsource `// process next document` part to another thread/machine/cluster.

The problem is the wire protocol itself is quite expensive to marshal/unmarshal bson data in singlethreaded nodejs, so you may find yourself in a situation when you hit the limit in optimisation on js level, and the only option is to scale up vertically - RAM and CPU (a single core spec, not number of cores).

Another solution could be an intermediate listener written on a language that can benefit from multiple cores, or use 3rd party systems, e.g. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/fundamentals/change-streams/  - it will take the hit, and you can build a cluster of worker to process the messages scaling horizontally.

Comment: As I understand rightly OOM issue is happening at .on statement which dumps all data at one on the system. But using await ....next() also will not fix the problem ? as it will receive only one document at one time..Then i can pass it to subprocess as well..

Comment: Yes, this idea is clearly communicated in the question, but thank you for rephrasing it in the comment. I imagine it arises from some misunderstanding how Javascript runtime works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop might help.   `.on` does not dump, and `.next`  does not receive. Nodejs is responsible to receive information on TCP level and register events for your code to process. You don't have control over it. `.on` uses callback interface to handle these events, and `.next` wraps it in Promise interface, but both are the same under the hood.